# Java PrimeFaces - DualListModel iteration

Tags: java, primefaces, iteration

EDIT:
I'm trying to iterate a list of values selected by user, brought by DualListModel from PrimeFaces.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
List<Department> dptsSelected = dptsDual.getTarget();
for (Department d : dptsSelected ) {
//do something
}
```

dptsDual:

```
DualListModel<Department> dptsDual;
```

I get the error when entering the FOR loop. The exception is throwed even before it enters the loop, it's throwed at the FOR.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Department
```

TIA

Comment: What exactly is the code being written in for loop ? Post more code.

Comment: Hi, I don't think that's the problem. I use the dptsSelected to pull them from my DB. But the exception is throwed even before it enters the loop, it's throwed at the FOR

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different things, DepartmentEnum and Department. First decide whether your requirement needs dptsDual as DualListModel of Department or DualListModel of DepartmentEnum

Now try this way ......

In the xhtml:

```
 <p:pickList value="#{myBean.myDepartment}" ....>
```

In the bean:

```
List<Department> selectedDepartments = new ArrayList<Department>();
List<Department> availableDepartments = getAvailableDepartments();

private DualListModel<Department> myDepartment;
myDepartment = new DualListModel<Department>(availableDepartments, selectedDepartments);
```

After Commit, selectedDepartments will have the Departments selected by the user

Comment: I'm sorry.. don't know if you saw my edit..

I did more tests, and found out that the problem isn't about the enum type, it's about iterating the selectedDepartment. It shows the String casting exception

Comment: my code is almost exactly like what you've done there, the problem is iterating the selectedDepartment

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
I was mistaken assuming that PF component could bring the Object back from the page. I assumed this because Java didn't protest when I did:

```
List<Department> dptsSelected = dptsDual.getTarget();
```

So.. maybe I should solve this by using a converter.

Thanks for the help guys.